# Azure Mobile Service hosted locally on IIS Express not acessable from a remote machine on same subnet

Tags: ios, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

Implementing the steps here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-configure-iis-express/

I tried to access the mobile service REST interface from iOS, Android and Windows based applications running on a remote machine performing GETs and POSTS all requests result in an "authorization has been denied for this request" response.

I am able to navigate to the mobile service website from the remote machine mentioned above, which is on the same subnet as the mobile service, however when clicking on the "try it out" link I am prompted to enter credentials. I tried entering the mobile service key, windows credentials and the credentials used when setting up the database none worked all resulted in a re-prompt for credentials.

The same Android and Windows applications work without issue when running on the machine the mobile service is running on. I have to use 10.0.2.2 for android app running in the emulator to get the loopback to work but otherwise the code is unchanged.

The azure mobile service is running in the debugger using Visual Studio 2013 with Update 3. Visual Studio was launched as an admin.

All three apps iOS, Android and Windows can access the same mobile service when its running in Azure (Cloud).

I have read that the mobile service, running in IISExpress, allows anonymous requests originating from localhost but I have not seen any mention about how to configure authentication when accessing remotely or if any adjustments are needed to authenticate properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Remote access for IIS Express is initially blocked

On Vista and Win7 or Win 8 run the following command with administratice Privileges

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://xxxxx:port/ user=everyone
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I have already implemented that. This enabled access to the azure mobile website. The REST interface is also reachable but returns the access denied http response so it seems there is an authentication issue.